# Xcode 6 - create UIImageView with equal heights changing with screen Orientation?

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout, size-classes

Why doesn't the height of my `UIImage` change when I run it on a different device? I set the height to 187 too all 4 images and I want display them with equal heights so they fill the full screen?

Here's the constraints for each image:
[image]

The image on the right is a screen-shot taken from Xcode. The image on the left is a screen-shot on iPhone 6

[image]

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: check my edited post. I included all the constraints and I am using auto-layout.

Comment: did u check my answer try that your problem will be solved

Comment: hey did u try that out

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImage`'s size doesn't change because it's the same JPG/PNG file, regardless of the device. What you need is a set of proper layout constraints.

I suggest the following approach:

1. Connect first image view's `top` to superview's `top`,
2. Connect last image view's `bottom` to superview's `bottom`,
3. Set `equal heights` for all image views.

Oh, and don't forget to set some constraints for horizontal axis.

Comment: Equal heights checkbox is greyed out. I can't select it.

Comment: @MartonZeisler You have to select multiple views to use equal heights checkbox.

Comment: I selected equal heights for all 4 images but it doesn't work. Check the image in my edited post of all the constraints I'm using for each image

Comment: Now it works!. But it gives me an error message:
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.

Comment: @akashivskyy Now it works but when I set the last images

Comment: @akashivskyy Now it works but when I set the last image view's bottom to superview's bottom it still compiles but returns an error: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Answer (score 1):

Add the constraints as the image below

> Select all of the image first and give constraint as below
>
> Step 1

[image]

> Step 2

[image]

> Step 3: You will achieve what you wants

[image]